# Sitecore 7 Search, cannot access a disposed object

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore

I've been working with some Sitecore 7 search code. Example below.

```
using (var context = Index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    // ....Build predicates

    var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(predicate); 
    return query.GetResults();
}
```

This works fine in SOLR, but when used with standard Lucene, whenever I reference a property in the `SearchResults<SearchResultItem>` returned by `GetResults()`, Sitecore errors with  "`Cannot access a disposed object`". It appears that `GetResults()` doesn't enumerate and still hangs on to the searchcontext.

Anyone come across this before and know how to fix? I've seen some articles suggesting having the `SearchContext` in application state, but ideally I want to avoid this.

Thanks

Ian

Comment: I was reading a tutorial from you [Sitecore 7 Search - a quickstart guide](http://www.bekagool.com/news-and-insights/sitecore-7-search-a-quickstart-guide). And I got the same error. It would be great for other persons if you update this tutorial as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that `SearchResults<T>` holds reference to `SearchHit` and the `LuceneSearchProvider` doesn't hold a reader open. The new version of Lucene automatically closes the reader. I think you might be returning the wrong type. You should probably do like this:

```
var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(predicate);
return query.ToList();
```

However make sure, that don't return too many. You should probably use take() etc.

Comment: Hi Jens, Thanks for your swift reply. Calling ToList() on the IQueryable first and then calling GetResults() on the IQueryable did the trick. Thanks Ian

Comment: Actually, on further testing that didn't work. Whenever I call GetResults it still requires a context. Is there an update to lucene I can get for this?

Comment: Why do you need to call the GetResults() method? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: GetResults will give you a hits collection, provide scoring information, TotalSearchResults etc. It saves some coding time and increases the performance of searches.

Comment: Hmm... I see your point and I looked into it. It seems that you have to get the information for the SearchResults<T> before you leave the using statement, which is kind of nasty. Maybe this should be reported as a bug, as the class is hooked up on the reader.

Comment: Tak for hjælpen. I'll report as a bug. Cheers Ian

Answer (score 0):

Is `GetResults()` returning a `List` or `IEnumerable`/`IQueryable`?

Try to return a list in case it isn't already.

```
return query.GetResults().ToList();
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your help. GetResults() returns a SearchResults<T> so no IEnumerable, but I did a ToList() on the IQueryable first and that seemed to enumerate and resolve the issue.